# CloudKit for Website and iOS

Tags: ios, web, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

I would like to build an iOS app and a website. I would like to store the images and related meta data on CloudKit.

I understand i can access the resources from the iOS app.

Would I be able to access the same resources for building the website ?

**Purpose:**

I would like to store the resources in one place and update once for it to be reflected for the website and iOS app.

**Question:**

1. Is this possible using CloudKit ? If so is there any documentation to build website using the resources and meta data in cloud kit ?
2. Is this the correct approach or should I be using something else.

**Note:**
I prefer to use iCloud if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while past, nobody has any views. A number of challenges on this.

If your going to work in IOS only, your going to have run a web server on an IOS device, doesn't really make sense. IOS devices like iPhones, iPads and iPods are highly portable, lower power devices, designed to work in WiFi environments, definitely not the right environment/device to create a web server on.

So your your in IOS and OSX, the latter the host for your web server. Is CloudKit the right medium, without knowing what you plan to host this is like asking the question "how long is a piece of string"... there isn't an answer; perhaps why nobody answered. My impression of cloudKit is it is easy to get started, a little bit of a challenge to move forward with and not perhaps a good environment for a complex setup given it has no server side logic and sharing data has some significant unknowns in it.

An alternative you might consider would be Dropbox, it too works under IOS and OSX as well as others, a very significant added bonus that it supports resource sharing, and has a far clearer indication on that side when it comes to charges.

CloudKit can share data via the public database, but you as the app developer are liable for the costs, so you need to be very careful with its use.

I leave it at that. More comments more than welcome.

Comment: Eighteen months on and I need to add to this answer. Apple has added sharing of private data to their cloudKit portfolio but its far more restrictive than Dropbox version, with anonymous sharing not an option in the new space.